# url rewrite debian

Tags: url-rewriting

I just got fresh debian VPS into my hands.
I installed url rewrite and simple things like this does seem to work

```
RewriteRule ^login$ /login.php
```

However this doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^cats$ /index.php?cat=cats
```

Anyone have idea why?

(it works on local xampp server + it worked on shared host I had)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you have mod_rewrite, and it's on. To do so, create an empty Php file, then add `<? phpinfo() ?>` and diplay it in your browser.
If it's "on" then you can go on.

---

If it's in a `.htaccess` file then try with / without the slashes.

```
RewriteRule ^cats$ /index.php?cat=cats
```

Or

```
RewriteRule ^/cats$ /index.php?cat=cats
```

And if that's not enough:

### Two hints:

If you're **not** in a hosted environment (= if it's *your own server* and *you **can** modify the virtual hosts*, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Thanks I've been try this thing with slashes but it doesn't seem to work.

I also tried adding that reweritelog option to .htacess but it doesn't seem to work either.

I tried with /tmp and with /var/www

Comment: There's not enough information about your provider and so on. I've updated my answer